# How to prove $|A:B|\geq |(C\cap A):(C\cap B)|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$A,B,C$ are three subgroups of a group $G$,  and $B$ is a subgroup of A.  Prove that   $|A:B|\geq |(C\cap A):(C\cap B)|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's call for B a subgroup of A $\mathcal{C}(B, A)$ the set of the left class of B in A, $\{xB, x \in A\}$
You can construct the function $\begin{array}{rcl} f: \mathcal{C}(C\cap B, C\cap A) & \to & \mathcal{C}(B, A) \\ x \cdot C\cap B & \to & x \cdot B \end{array}$

You can verify that f is well defined and injective and this gives you the desired inequality.

Edit : I don't know why I didn't use the usual notation $A/B$, but it's exactly what I meant by $\mathcal C(B, A)$